# Python: parse all files in a folder

Tags: python, xml, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to parse allthe files in a folder with help of a python loop and then store it as a dataframe, I am using following script

```
path='C:\\Users\\manusharma\\Training'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    a = ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf-8', method='text')
    c = a.replace('\n', '')
    df = df.append({'text': c, 'type': 'abc'}, ignore_index=True)
```

and my path file has following files

```
abc1.xml
abc2.xml
abc3.xml
abc4.xml
abc5.xml
```

every time, I ran my code it show me an error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc1'
```

though it is there, where am I making an error? Appreciate every help

Comment: `os.path,join(path, filename)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns only filenames (not full paths).

You can try to use `glob.glob(path + '/*.xml')` instead of `os.listdir(path)`

Demo:

```
In [111]: path = 'd:/temp/xml'

In [112]: os.listdir(path)
Out[112]: ['1.xml', '2.xml', '3.xml', 'bla.tmp']

In [113]: glob.glob(path + '/*.xml')
Out[113]: ['d:/temp/xml\\1.xml', 'd:/temp/xml\\2.xml', 'd:/temp/xml\\3.xml']
```